# In odoo How to catch product list on change event in POS screen

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-16

I am working on a module making something when any change happens
in the product grid in the POS screen 
this is my code

```
/** @odoo-module **/
const ProductScreen = require('point_of_sale.ProductScreen');
const Registries = require('point_of_sale.Registries');
const { Gui } = require('point_of_sale.Gui');


export const ChangePOSGrid = (ProductScreen) =>
  class extends ProductScreen {
       //@override
        async _onClickPay() {
           console.log('Code here');
        }
}
Registries.Component.extend(ProductScreen, ChangePOSGrid);
```

In this code, I already catch the Pay Button click event
but I need to catch the product list change event

how to do this can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution
and I'll share it here

this the solution

```
export const ChangePOSGrid = (ProductScreen) =>
  class extends ProductScreen {
       //@override
       async _updateSelectedOrderline() {
          //code here 
       }
    
       //@override
        async _onClickPay() {
           console.log('Code here');
        }
}
```